Azimuth and Elevation angle in Spherical coordinates w.r.t to a given point
I am given a point $A = (x_b, y_b,z_b)$ and $C =(x_c, y_c, z_c)$ in cartesian co-ordinates. I am trying to compute the azimuth and elevation angle  point $C$ make w.r.t point $A$.
Can I compute this by just converting $(x_c -x_a, y_c-y_a,z_c-z_a)$ to spherical co-ordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$  as given in wikipedia?
It would be great if someone can confirm my approach is correct?

Note that the elevation angle is $90^\circ-\theta$

@Andrei Thanks. But my approach of subtracting the coordinates and then finding the spherical coords is correct, right?

Yes, it is the right approach.
